# installed pip on windows 10 but pip --version has Traceback error

Tags: python

I did already download py get-pip.py and run it successfully on Windows

But got this error when typing **pip --version**:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    File "runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    File "C:\dev\python\Scripts\pip3.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a Python script that uses some bootstrapping logic to install pip.

Download the script, from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py.

Open a terminal/command prompt, cd to the folder containing the get-pip.py file and run:

```
C:> py get-pip.py
```

Comment: problem is I did that already (updated my post) ;)